# Number of Tunes Possible in this Google Doodle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I was recently playing around in this [Google Doodle](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+doodle+music). Was wondering how many unique tunes can be created using this tool.

Since there are $16$ x $11$ dots for each instrument, and $4$ different instruments, is the answer $({2^{176}})^4- 1$?

This number seems crazily large. I'm not sure if I'm making a huge calculation mistake somewhere.

Is my answer correct? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Your link is not specific enough for me to identify the doodle, but going by your description that calculation seems correct to me. [John Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%B233%E2%80%B3) might disagree with the minus one though.

Comment: Here's the direct [link](https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2017/fischinger/fischinger17.9.html?hl=en). For some reason, the doodle doesn't work if opened directly. That's why I had linked to the search page leading to the doodle.